Which component of coroutines executes suspend functions
I recently tried to figure out who is actually responsible to execute the suspend functions
So
I created some suspend functions in my coroutine
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

for (x in 1..20){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{
        for (i in 1..5) {
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                myFun(i, Thread.currentThread().name)
            }else{
                myFun2(i, Thread.currentThread().name)
            }
        }
    }
}


Thread.sleep(3000000)  //this is just to wait for all coroutines to complete, ignore it

}
suspend fun myFun(n : Int, tName : String) {
    println("myFun method called from Thread = $tName, for i = $n")
    println("myFun -> executing on Thread = ${Thread.currentThread().name}, came from Thread = $tName")
    delay(1000)
    val x = n * n;
    println("myFun -> performing square operation on Thread = ${Thread.currentThread().name}, for i = $n came from Thread = $tName")

    myFun3(x, Thread.currentThread().name, tName);
    println("myFun method finished for i = $n, on Thread = ${Thread.currentThread().name} came from Thread = $tName")
}


suspend fun myFun2(n : Int, tName: String){
    println("myFun2 method called from Thread = $tName, for i = $n")
    println("myFun2 -> executing on Thread = ${Thread.currentThread().name} came from Thread = $tName")
    delay(1000)
    val x = n * n * n;
    println("myFun2 -> performing cube operation on Thread = ${Thread.currentThread().name} for i = $n came from Thread = $tName")
    myFun3(x, Thread.currentThread().name, tName);
    println("myFun2 method finished for i = $n, on Thread = ${Thread.currentThread().name}, came from Thread = $tName")
}

suspend fun myFun3(n : Int, parentFunThread : String, cThread: String){
    if(!fun3Thread.equals(parentFunThread) || !fun3Thread.equals(cThread) || !parentFunThread.equals(cThread)){
        println("--------------------------------------------Found-------------------------")
    }
    println("myFun3 method called from Thread = $parentFunThread, for x = $n through coroutineThread = $cThread")
    println("myFun3 -> executing on Thread = $fun3Thread, came from Thread = $parentFunThread, coroutineThread = $cThread")
    println("myFun3 -> final value of x = $n onThread = $fun3Thread, came from Thread = $parentFunThread, coroutineThread = $cThread")
    println("myFun3 method finished for x = $n, on Thread = $fun3Thread, came from Thread = $parentFunThread, coroutineThread = $cThread")
}

Since I created these suspend functions in my own, there execution was pretty simple like normal functions, They were not behaving like (pausing the current coroutine, detaching the coroutine from the underlying Thread : making the Thread available for other coroutines)
They were all executing on the same thread on which they invoked.
Underlying threads were switched when I invoked inbuilt suspend function(delay(1000)) in my suspend functions, results were different.
Since there are multiple ways of suspend functions like (api call method in retrofit, room db query function, and delay function like here)
My question is which component of android executes these suspend functions?
Thanks in advance.`

Simple explanation:
If there is no suspension, the function runs on the same thread.
Otherwise the coroutine will pause, the thread will freed for other tasks, and the coroutine will may resume on a different thread.
Tasks such as delaying, network calls can switch threads in built-in suspend functions.
Conclusion
All these operations are managed by the Kotlin coroutine lib.
Which thread they will run on is determined by the Dispatcher.
CoroutineDispatcher
